# Opening ClearCase Activity Properties window from command line

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I'm sure I was able to pop up the ClearCase Activity Properties window from the command line at one point.

Does anybody how to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be one of the executable in `<IBM/Rational/ClearCase>/bin`, but you can also try (using [`cleartool describe`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm)):

```
cleartool descr -graph activity:myActivity@\myPVob
```

Otherwise `clearprojexp.exe` launched the UCM project manager itself.

Comment: The "cleartool describe -graph" was the command I was looking for. It does exactly what I needed.